# JQuery SubDiv Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Sorry if the question is fool .. I have no jquery experience and I need Help with something that may be easy

I have a JQuery script that uses a selector to hide content (Social Locker)
 for example

```
$(".post_message_1").sociallocker({
```

my problem is that when I apply this code to a div with subelement .. It don't work 
for example

```
<div id="post_message_1">
    <blockquote class="postcontent restore ">
        Content Here 
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

If I use selector `$(".postcontent").sociallocker({`
it works fine and content is hidden
but when I use `$(".post_message_1").sociallocker({` 
it doesn't work 
The problem here I want to hide the  content for `post_message_1` not `postcontent` as `postcontent` is not specific and used in all text `<divs>`s
I hope this is clear

Comment: `$("#post_message_1")`

Answer (score 1):

You got wrong jQuery selector. `#` is for ID and `.` is for class.

Answer (score 1):

in your code post_message_1 is set an an id not a class.

so use

```
$("#post_message_1").sociallocker({})
```

instead of

```
$(".post_message_1").sociallocker({})
```

or add class="post_message_1" in your div.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".post_message_1")` is a JQuery class selector while `$("#post_message_1")` is an id selector.
Please view the **[JQuery selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)** for more information

Answer (score 0):

use the id selector

```
$("#post_message_1").sociallocker({})
```